# How can I apply the [[nodiscard]] attribute to a lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, attributes, language-lawyer, c++17

I want to prevent people from calling the lambda without handling the return value.

Clang 4.0 refuses everything I've tried, compiling with -std=c++1z:

```
auto x = [&] [[nodiscard]] () { return 1; };
// error: nodiscard attribute cannot be applied to types
```

```
auto x = [[nodiscard]] [&]() { return 1; };
// error: expected variable name or 'this' in lambda capture list
```

```
auto x [[nodiscard]] = [&]() { return 1; };
// warning: nodiscard attribute only applies to functions, methods, enums, and classes
```

```
[[nodiscard]] auto x = [&]() { return 1; };
// warning: nodiscard attribute only applies to functions, methods, enums, and classes
```

```
auto x = [&]() [[nodiscard]] { return 1; };
// error: nodiscard attribute cannot be applied to types
```

Is this some sort of bug in clang or a hole in the standard?

Comment: Is your intention to apply the attribute to the return value of the lambda, or to the lambda itself? Because the latter doesn't make much sense...

Comment: [expr.prim.lambda] would suggest `[&]() [[nodiscard]] { return 1; }`.

Comment: ...however,  [dcl.attr.nodiscard] does not allow that particular attribute in a lambda. If I had to guess, I'd say it's because there's little use for this: lambdas are usually passed as callbacks to some other part of the code, and so the nodiscardiness cannot be checked anyway.

Comment: Hm, it looks like your edited question already contains the exact answer you need as part of the diagnostic :-S

Comment: I use them often as local functions in which case the nodiscardiness would be relevant, unless I misunderstand nodiscardiness completely.

Comment: Sure, but if the use is only local, you can kind of *see* whether you're calling them. The value of marking API function as nodiscard is that things like `vector::empty` don't get misunderstood by third parties. If it's your own code, it's much less of an issue.

Comment: Yes I can see and control my own usage but not that of my colleagues.  In this case the outer function must "return myLambda()".  There may be another way to structure this but I'm not sure that justifies this as an exception in the standard.  I'm not sure how you arrive at the conclusion that lambdas are excluded either, unless "lambda" != "function" in pedantic standards interpretation.

Comment: I thought lambdas were just syntactic sugar for defining and instantiating ad-hoc classes with an overloaded `operator()`.

Comment: FWIW `GCC 7` allows this: `auto x = [&]() [[nodiscard]] { return 1; };`

Comment: Yes, thanks.  GCC7 allows the syntax and gives the correct warning.

Comment: @DanOlson : It does compile with GCC7+, but I don't see any relevant warning for GCC7 or GCC8. What warning are you seeing?

Comment: @ildjarn Sorry, I mean the warning is produced as expected when the lambda is called and the return value is ignored, not when the lambda is declared.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You [can't apply `nodiscard` to lambdas](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr.nodiscard#1), but you can write a wrapper:

```
template <typename F>
struct NoDiscard {
    F f;
    NoDiscard(F const& f) : f(f) {}
    template <typename... T>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto operator()(T&&... t) const
      noexcept(noexcept(f(std::forward<T>(t)...))) {
        return f(std::forward<T>(t)...);
    }
};

int main() {
    NoDiscard([](int i) {return i;})(0);
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BdT5TXem9Qo0zZau).

Comment: How about adding `const noexcept(noexcept(f(std::forward<T>(t)...)))` to the `operator()` for nitpickers like me out there? :)

Comment: @Rostislav I'm not sure the `const` is a strict improvement, as it prevents us from using non-`const` `operator()`s in `F`, although that admittedly matters less for lambdas.

Comment: Yeah, had my brain strictly on lambdas and their `operator(...) const`. Probably `const` and `non-const` overloads in the wrapper would be proper. But all this is definitely use-case dependent.

Answer (score 2):

In C++23 you can do it like this:

```
auto lambda = [] [[nodiscard]] (/*parameters*/)
{
    // ...
};
```

The parameter list is optional. Spaces around `[[...]]` are optional.

Template parameters `<...>` (if any) go before the attributes.