# [[nodiscard]] to a function pointer

Tags: c++, c++17, nodiscard

I want to use a third party functions, which provides its API through a struct full of function pointers. for example:

```cpp
struct S {
    using p_func1 = int(*)(int, int);
    p_func1 func1;
    using p_func2 = int(*)(char*);
    p_func2 func2;
}
```

The third party library initializes this struct.
The return values of those functions (func1, func2) needs to be checked, and I was hoping I could somehow manifest on the `[[discard]]` attribute to make sure the return values are checked.

Is there any way to do this, while maintaining the ABI of the struct?

Edit:
So far, the best I could come up with is having another struct, like so:

```cpp
struct S_wrap {
    S orig;
    [[nodiscard]] int func1(int a, int b){ return orig.func1(a, b); }
    [[nodiscard]] int func2(char* a){ return orig.func2(a); }
}
```

I'm hoping there's something better

Comment: I'm not saying that it's a dupe but the accepted answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43686374/how-can-i-apply-the-nodiscard-attribute-to-a-lambda) could do the trick.

Comment: @paler123 That answer is indeed insightful. I'm still looking for an answer that would suite my case the best way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your wrapper (or any wrapper) is the only way to go. The attribute applies to the function declarator-id (its name), not the function's type. So it's lost when using a pointer, nor can it be applied to the pointer itself:

> **[dcl.attr.nodiscard]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.attr.nodiscard#1) The attribute-token `nodiscard` may be applied to the
>   declarator-id in a function declaration or to the declaration of a
>   class or enumeration. It shall appear at most once in each
>   attribute-list and no attribute-argument-clause shall be present.

So if the function pointers are returning an `int`, the only way to prevent discarding the result is to use some sort of wrapper with a named function (or `operator()`) that has the attribute applied.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GCC you may use `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))` instead. Unlike `[[nodiscard]]` it does work on `typedef` or `using`:

```cpp
struct S2 {
    using p_func1 = __attribute__((warn_unused_result)) int(*)(int, int);
    p_func1 func1;
    using p_func2 = __attribute__((warn_unused_result)) int(*)(char*);
    p_func2 func2;
};
```

Interestingly, Clang accepts this code but doesn't use the attribute and will not issue warnings. Also, it requires the `__attribute__` to be placed at the front (as above), and will reject when it is placed at the end, before `;`.

You can go further by using `[[gnu::warn_unused_result]]` instead:

```cpp
struct S {
    using p_func1 = int(*)(int, int) [[gnu::warn_unused_result]];
    p_func1 func1;
    using p_func2 = int(*)(char*) [[gnu::warn_unused_result]];
    p_func2 func2;
};
```

With GCC you can place the `[[gnu::warn_unused_result]]` both at the end (as shown above) or at the beginning:

```cpp
using p_func1 = [[gnu::warn_unused_result]] int(*)(int, int);
```

as you would with `[[nodiscard]]` on a function. However, Clang and MSVC (and probably other) will reject the second form. For the first form, Clang warns about ignored attributes since it is applied to type.

See full sample here: https://godbolt.org/z/qEfEeoqeM.